# monero-wallet-cli mining hash rate

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, cpu-mining, nodes

I am mining from a Remote Node using monero-wallet-cli and using the start_mining command.

1. How do I find out the hash rate?
2. How do I maximise the mining to use as much of the CPU as possible?

Comment: If you have two questions, post twice. There are many answers about maximizing hash rate already.

Answer (score 1):

The wallet does not report on the daemon mining hash rate, you will have to run `status` in the deamon, or use RPC directly, eg:

`curl -v -X POST http://NODEIP:NOTEPORT/mining_status -d '{}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Then replace NODEIP and NODEPORT with the IP and port of your remote daemon.

Note that this RPC will only work if you did not set your daemon to use restricted RPC mode (which is recommended if strangers have access to your daemon's RPC).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the command `show_hr`.
2. Find out the total cache size of your CPU (in MB) and divide by 2MB, find out the total number of cores your CPU has, whichever is lower, use that as the thread count when you run start_mining.

Comment: are you saying that the thread count equals the lower of the number of CPU cores or the total cache size of CPU divided by 2 ?  Won't CPU cores always be lower?

Comment: No, definitely not. CPU cores will not always be lower. I have some machines with way more cores than CPU cache / 2.

Comment: Which bash command do you use out CPU cache?

Comment: On Linux, `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cache size'`